# WSO2 and JPA configuration (JNDI)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wso2, osgi

I am trying to use JPA through WSO2 ESB. I have my entities in Module A, which is bundled to Module B, because Module A generates JAR and in WSO2 OSGi modules should be used. 
In Module A I have got:

- entities package with all entities
- persistence.xml under /resources/META-INF folder

  ```
  <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
  <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/PathToJNDI</non-jta-data-source>
  <class>com.moduleA.entities.Locks</class>
  <class>com.moduleA.entities.Logs</class>
  <class>com.moduleA.entities.MessageContent</class>
  <class>com.moduleA.entities.Messages</class>
  <class>com.moduleA.entities.Parts</class>
  <class>com.moduleA.entities.Recipients</class>
  <class>com.moduleA.entities.Test</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit" />
  </properties>
  ```

To get persistence properties I am using JNDI. It is configured in WSO2 panel.

And these elements are packed to Module B via maven-bundle-plugin.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
          <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
          <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
            <Export-Package>com.coig,com.coig.*,pl.coig.*, com.moduleA.entities.*</Export-Package>
            <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
            <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
            <JPA-PersistenceUnits>JPAPU</JPA-PersistenceUnits>
            <Import-Package>
                *, org.hibernate*,org.hibernate.proxy, javassist.util.proxy,
                javax.persistence;version="1.1.0";jpa="2.0",
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc, ${extra.packages},
                javax.transaction.*,
                *;resolution:=optional,
                org.osgi.framework
            </Import-Package>
            <Embed-Dependency>entities</Embed-Dependency>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

After Maven building I can see that Module B Manifest contains all things from configuration.

Then, I am trying to get list of all records from database in WSO2 Mediator Project in mediate() method.

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("openjpa.ConnectionDriverName","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
properties.put("openjpa.ConnectionFactoryName","jdbc/PathToJNDI");

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAPU",properties);
try{
    EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    try{
        log.severe("EntityManagerFactory and Entity manager created");
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        try{
            log.severe("Transaction started");
            Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Test.findAll", Test.class);
            List<Test> list = q.getResultList();
            for ( Test s : list ) {
                log.severe(s.getName());
            }
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e1){
            if(entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()){
                entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            log.log(Level.INFO, e1.getMessage(), e1);
        }
    }catch (Throwable e){
        log.severe("EntityManager exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}catch(Exception e2){
    log.severe("EntityManagerFactory exception: " + e2.getMessage());
}finally {
    emf.close();
}
```

Is it necessary to provide driver and factory name in properties to map and then use it to create EntityManagerFactory? Without these properties I get warning, that OpenJPA does not find Driver of Datasource.

I am getting message that app did not find classpath for Test.class, despite it is provided in Maven dependencies and package with entities is imported in maven-bundle-plugin under MediatorProject pom. I do not want to add to MediatorProject Path folder with entities, but I want to import them via maven-bundle or some other way (if you know how to make it works :))

What I should change in my configuration to satisfy the JPA transaction?

Comment: The solution is simple. You have to pack your project (with entities in my case) into bundle and set properly apache-felix-plugin to generate MANIFEST